# C#：メインウインドウを閉じると同時に、別ウインドウを閉じることが出来ない

Tags: c#, wpf

メインウインドウを閉じると同時に、
別で開いているウインドウも一緒に閉じたいのですが、下のコードでは閉じることが出来ません。
方法があればご教授をお願いします。

```
～メインウインドウクラス～

　　　　　//メインウインドウを閉じるときのイベント
        private void closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
　　　　　　　//別ウインドウを閉じる
            Window setWindow = new settingWindow(this);
            setWindow.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> //別ウインドウを閉じる
>   Window setWindow = **new** settingWindow(this);
>   setWindow.close();

はnew（新しい）ウィンドウを閉じるコードであり、既にある「別ウィンドウ」を閉じるコードではありません。

[Application.ShutdownMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode(v=vs.110).aspx)をOnMainWindowCloseにすれば特にコードを書くことなく実現できますが、これは期待するものと異なりますか？

Comment: 返答ありがとうございます。
解決することが出来ました。